# Как инициализировать глобальный массив внешней переменной?

Tags: c, линковка, extern

Пусть имеются два файла с исходным кодом. В первом объявим `extern`-переменную `variable` и попытаемся инициализировать ей массив:

```
// first.c

extern const int variable;

int values[4] = {0, variable, 0, 0};

int main() {}
```

Во втором объявим и инициализируем саму переменную `variable`:

```
// second.c

const int variable = 123;
```

Попытаемся скомпилировать:

```
gcc -o test first.c second.c
```

На этапе компиляции возникнет ошибка:

> first.c:5:22: error: initializer element is not constant

Хотя на этапе линковки она (по идее) может быть разрешена. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то способ решить эту проблему, кроме слияния исходных файлов?

Comment: Видимо потому, что для первого файла эта переменная extern, компилятор не знает ее значения наверняка и не может подставить. В любом случае, один маленький дейфайн должен помочь

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за отклик! А как Вы предполагаете применить дефайн в таком контексте? Если просто в качестве константы, то в ситуации, благодаря которой возник вопрос, подобный способ кажется малопригодным. Пытался сделать собственную реализацию локалей (в курсе про `gettext`, но для моей задачи это слишком замудрённо), примерно [как тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433984) описано, при этом хотел ещё и раскидать строки для разных локалей по отдельным `.c`-файлам - в этом месте и произошёл облом :)

Comment: в отдельном хедере сделать `#define VARIABLE 123`, а потом `const int variable = VARIABLE;`, `int values[4] = {0, VARIABLE, 0, 0};`. Хотя в Вашем случае похоже легче написать кодогенератор и сбросить все в один файл

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, понял Вашу идею. Думал о варианте с хедерами, но это всё-таки далеко не каноническое решение - если в локалях достаточно много строк, то при малейшем изменении придётся полностью перекомпилировать связанный с ними сишный файл, и заодно подцепить их все

Comment: а точно нужно все переводы хранить прям в бинарнике?  и так ли их там много, что бы это уже было проблемой?

Comment: @KoVadim, на оба вопроса ответ отрицательный - просто интересно, как можно было бы решить именно такую задачу, когда все переводы в одном бинарнике, но при этом компилируется каждый отдельно

Comment: Наверное на практике проще всего вызвать в начале main функцию, которая проинициализирует подобные extern массивы. Дело в том, что перед  вызовом main стартовый код гарантировано пропишет все внешние переменные их инициализаторами

Comment: @avp, вот к такому варианту в итоге и пришёл. Но всё-таки надеялся, что можно без подобного костыля

Comment: Это не костыль, скорее KISS принцип, только на котором и может быть основана успешная архитектура.

Comment: @SunnyCove - "на этапе линковки она (по идее) может быть разрешена" - Но ведь компиллер **не** говорит, что ссылка не разрешена. Он говоит, что это переменная. а **не** константа. И это любопытно..

Comment: @Sergey, и правда. Clang выдаёт несколько иную ошибку: `first.c:5:21: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant`